# "This is a book" what is the role of "book"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, learning

What is *book* in this sentence ?

- *This is a book*.

Is that an Object?

What are the nouns that come in the sentences with *to be*'s?

Like *my friend* in *He is my friend*?

Answer (score 3):

> This is a book.

I think you want to ask about the noun phrase *a book*. The word *book* is the Head of the noun phrase *a book*. The phrase *a book* however, is a Complement of the verb *be*.

Specifically, it is a Predicative Complement. This type of Complement gives us a description of the Subject or Object of a verb. They are usually noun phrases, adjective phrases or preposition phrases:

Subject oriented Predicative Complements:

- He is **happy**
- He is **a tyrant**
- He is **on fire**

Object  Oriented Predicative Complements:

- We elected her **treasurer**
- This made her **curious**
- She left him **in a spin**

Notice that when a Complement is an Object, it usually introduces a new entity into the sentence. Predicative Complements describe one of the entities already in the sentence. They usually don't introduce a new one.

Objects can normally become the Subjects of passivised sentences. Predicative Complements can't:

- *Treasurer was elected her by us.
- *Book is been this.

---

It's probably worth pointing out, however, that there is no restriction on Predicative Complements occurring in passive voice sentences per se. The main point is that they can't be the *Subject* of passivised sentences. The following is therefore perfectly grammatical:

- She was elected treasurer by us.

In this example it's the Direct Object *her/she* which is the subject of the sentence. The Predicative Complement still appears as a Complement of the verb *elected*.

Answer (score 3):

The auxiliary verb *be* is used for the Passive construction, for the Progressive construction, in any number of idioms, and also for any predicate that is not a verb. Since verbs are always predicates, we don't have to call them "predicate verbs"; but since nouns and adjectives are often not predicates, it is customary to call them ***Predicate Nouns*** and ***Predicate Adjectives*** when they **are** used as predicates. Both predicate nouns and predicate adjectives require an auxiliary *be*.

In the example sentences, *book* and *friend* are both predicate nouns, and that's where the *is* comes from; it's a required auxiliary verb for a predicate noun. Note that predicate nouns are really noun phrases -- they can have articles, quantifiers, possessives, adjectives, and so on, just like any NP; in

- *That man [was [the most ridiculous parody of a public servant that I've ever seen]].*

the verb phrase is the outer bracket, and the predicate noun is the inner, for instance.

Executive summary: Use auxiliary ***be*** for Predicate Adjectives

- *I am **firm**.*
- *You are **stubborn**.*

**and** for Predicate Nouns

- *He is **a pig-headed fool**.*

Comment: And presumably for Predicate PPs too?

Comment: Or do people use the term *Predicate Adjectives* to cover PPs as well?

Comment: Any adjective or noun predicate can be elaborated as a phrase. This fact is the basis of several different kinds of syntax, like X-Bar Theory.

Comment: As for PPs, generally they're adverbial, like _at noon, on the beach,_ etc. When those show up as predicates, one usually can add the appropriate stative predicate optionally: _He is (located) at the beach; The parade is (scheduled) at noon_ and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

It's a complement. It completes the subject by telling more about it.

It's not an object, as it's receiving no action. The verb *to be* is acting like an equals sign, equating the subject with its complement.

Other verbs that can take complements are "seem," "smell," and "feel." Sometimes an English speaker might overcorrect and say "I felt badly." They think an adverb is required. But unless they meant to say they were doing a poor job of feeling, they should say, "I felt bad." The adjective, "bad" tells us something about the subject, or at least the emotional state of the subject.